# Restricting what assemblies can call into an assembly

Tags: c#, security

We have a need to make sure `Child1` can only be called by `Parent1` and not by any malware or rogue application trying to data from `Child1`.

I have both `Parent1` and `Child1` strongly named with the same certificate.  I am using the attribute line below in the `Child1` class.

```
[PublisherIdentityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, CertFile = @"calltest.cer")]
```

I have no code or attribute additions in the parent1 assembly, just have it strongly named with the same cert as the `Child1` assembly.

The problem is that I wrote another assembly `Evil1` which is not signed by anything and it can still call into the `Child1` assembly.

**Child Assembly**

```
namespace Child1
{
   [PublisherIdentityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, CertFile = @"C:\calltest.cer")]
   public class Child1
   {
       public int AddNumber(int x, int y)
       {
          return x + y;
       }
   }
 }
```

**Parent Assembly**

```
public class Parent1
{
    public int DoMath1(int x, int y)
    {
        Child1.Child1 chd = new Child1.Child1();
        return chd.AddNumber(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not played around with permissions before but when I've seen similar things before its been done by making the child internal and using `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` to make them visible to the parent assembly. No idea if you can do it the way you are trying.

Comment: You are using the CAS mechanism, which were deprecated in .NET 4.0. In particular, the documentation for `PublisherIdentityPermission` says that "Starting with the .NET Framework 4, identity permissions are not used." However, I have a question for you: what system are you trying to protect, by denying access to the `Child1` library? For example, if the system that you are trying to protect is a file on the user's hard disk, then the malware can modify the file directly anyway.

Comment: the child DLL is the gateway to some data and while the machine is locked down very heavily, the security group is looking for this extra security.  Thanks for mentioning that CAS is not in .NET 4.  I missed that.  We are .NET 4 and I will look for alternatives

Comment: The fundamental problem is that, if you have malware with a given user's access on that machine, then there is fundamentally nothing that you can do to prevent that malware from doing anything that that user is authorized to do.

Comment: And, to be candid, it seems you expect a *very* targeted attack - I seriously doubt that a run-of-the-mill malware will inspect DLLs by itself to try and find if any of them seems worth hacking. And if you are the victim of an attacker who knows to target your `Child1` library, and he already has malware that has the same level of trust than the `Parent1` application, then no protection you can offer will work - if worst comes to worst, the attacker will extract the loaded memory image from RAM, inspect it to remove any protection, and run his modified version.

Comment: That is, your mission parameters - where the attacker already has working malware on the workstation, and the attacker also knows that he attacks some system that is accessed via library `Child1`, sound seriously more like "Mission: Impossible" than a reasonable scenario.